# Removing a folder at the end of a script that is installing software

Tags: powershell

I have a script that is copying a file from the server into the `c:\windows\temp\` to install Microsoft office. I am trying to figure out how I can then delete the copy off the local drive that I had to copy over from the server to do the install. I am curious if there is a way to make sure the install is complete before removing the files that it may need.

```cs
Function Get-FileName{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [String]$Filter = "|*.*",
    [String]$InitialDirectory = "C:\")

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = $Filter
    [void]$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$file = Get-FileName -InitialDirectory $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Filter "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
ForEach ($item in (Get-Content $file)) {
    $sitem = $item.Split("|")
    $computer = $sitem[0].Trim()
    $user = $sitem[1].Trim()

    $filepath = Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\"
    If ($filepath -eq $false) {
    Get-Service remoteregistry -ComputerName $computer | Start-Service

    Copy-Item -Path "\\server\Install\Office2010" -Destination "\\$computer\c$\windows\temp\" -Container -Recurse -Force

    <#
    $InstallString = '"C:\windows\temp\Office2010\setup.exe"'
    ([WMICLASS]"\\$computer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").Create($InstallString)

    "$computer" + "-" + "$(Get-Date)" | Out-File -FilePath "\\server\Install\Office2010\RemoteInstallfile.txt" -Append
    #>
    } Else {
        "$computer" + "_Already_Had_Software_" + "$(Get-Date)" | Out-File -FilePath "\\server\Install\Office2010\RemoteInstallfile.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

Was wondering if I could insert the piece below somewhere in this code to then go ahead and remove this folder?

```cs
$folderToDelete = "\\$computer\c$\windows\temp\"

$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
[io.directory]::delete($folderToDelete, $true)
$fso = New-Object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject
$fso.DeleteFolder($folderToDelete,$true)
if (Test-Path ($folderToDelete)) {
 New-Item -ItemType directory -Path .\EmptyFolder
 robocopy .\EmptyFolder $folderToDelete /mir
 Remove-Item .\EmptyFolder
 Remove-Item $folderToDelete
}
```

But I am not sure if the install would not be complete before the delete would take place? Has anyone ever done anything like this and would like to share some guidance?

Comment: You can grab the PID from that WMI method you're using to launch the installer, than while Get-process -id $thatpid, wait

Answer (score 2):

Since you start the process with `([WMICLASS]"\\$computer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").Create($InstallString)` it's a little harder to pass the PID than with `Start-Process or Invoke-Command`. So like Chris N said you want to grab the PID and wait for it to close. But since `.waitforexit()` isn't supported on remote machines, you'll get to do it one of two ways.

Via Invoke Command: (which may not be an option since you did not use this to run the setup command in the first place)

```
$PID = (Get-Process setup -computername $computer).id
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputer -ScriptBlock { param($ProcessId) Wait-Process -ProcessId $ProcessId } -ArgumentList $PID
```

A while loop, checking if the process has completed:

```
$processid = (Get-Process setup -computername $computer).id
while ($null -ne $processid) {
    Start-Sleep -m 250
}
```

Also your, delete section seems unnecessarily complex.

```
$folderToDelete = "\\$computer\c$\example"
if (Test-Path ($folderToDelete)) {
    Remove-Item $folderToDelete -Recurse -Force
}
```

One more thing, setting ErrorActionPreference to Silently Continue in your script is generally bad practice. Usually the answer is a proper error catching with Try/Catch

Comment: can i ask you something as well. The script I have isnt working properly and just spit out some weird messages. I was curious if you could tell me what this means because its not installing microsoft office. __GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ProcessId        : 
ReturnValue      : 8
PSComputerName   :

Comment: Unfortunately [that error isn't too useful.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx) It means Unknown Error. It's coming from the Create Method of the Win32_Process class that you are using to start setup. In context of your script it means "Couldn't start setup.exe for an unknown reason"

Comment: hmmm maybe I cant use a variable? maybe it needs the path inside .Create() ?

Comment: can you show me how to insert the delete portion into my script everything I keep doing is completely breaking the script